# Trouble horizontally centering elements on page

Tags: css, centering

I've tried everything I can think of, and am still unable to horizontally center the elements on this page:

http://www.telodesign.com/SET/?page_id=191

I'm sure it's just something I'm missing in the CSS, but am completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
#setflow-page p, #setflow-page table {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to your CSS and it will be centered.

Since both the paragraph and the table has relative width set (60% and 70%) it won't fill the whole DIV, so setting text-align: center wont help. You need to set its outer horisontal margins to auto.

Comment: Thanks so much--simple, but I was just missing it. Much appreciated!

Comment: As a courtesy here at SO, you should mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you. You will be rewarded 2 reputation scores and I gets 15.

Comment: I was wondering how to do that--thank you. And thanks again for the help.